Cartoon movie about Greek gods?
I'm looking for a fairly old (with the graphics and stuff) cartoon movie that is, I think, about Greek gods, maybe Hercules or Zeus. 
He gets into trouble for breaking a statue so he gets sent on this adventure with Pegasus. In their first trial, they meet this ferret or some animal like that, and they get shot with glass. 
Their second one is Medusa. The last one is a dragon and then turns out to be the character's father, stuff happens and the ferret animal turns into a girl. 

Welcome to the community. Answering the following questions will help us to respond. Any other plot details? What year did you see it? What was the language? Can you estimate the year and country of production? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

The movie you are looking for is The Amazing Feats of Young Hercules.
As the title suggests, this 30 minute animated short film is about Greek God Hercules's adventure at young age. 
Hercules destroys a statue of Zeus using thunderbolts. This makes Zeus angry and wishes that he should make Hercules learn about power and responsibility. Then Zeus gives him a task of completing four challenges and accompanied by a chariot of Pegasus.
From Wikipedia page of the movie: 

The Amazing Feats of Young Hercules is a 1997 animated short film about the Greek mythological hero Hercules as a teenager who longs to be free and be just like Zeus, the supreme Greek god. Zeus gives him the chance to by giving him four challenges. Each of the challenges contain monsters and all sorts of things he has to get past. Along the way, Hercules meets a talking loud mouth female sable named Falina who tells Hercules that she used to be a princess until the day Hera turned her into a sable when she mentions that Aphrodite was prettier than Hera. As a result, she tags along with Hercules. It was distributed by UAV Entertainment.




